What isolation level for select query: 'snapshot' vs 'read uncommitted'
It is true that the for select query 'read uncommitted' isolation level is fester then 'snapshot'?
Both case do not respect object locking and results will be the same for select query?
Sorry for My English.

No, results can be different. 'snapshot' will not return inconsistent results while 'read uncommitted' can do it.

Read uncommitted can return incorrect data, why would you ever use this? Snapshot is fast enough, are you seeing a particular performance issue?

Both of these allows reading the data without locking the target row. But Read uncommitted allows you to read changes which is not committed yet also known as Dirty read which is something to avoid in prod environments in most cases. Snapshot isolation makes the use of row versioning without waiting for the transactions that may modifying the rows but returning committed data. Preferably this will be your friend unless your app can have dirty reads in that case  you can use Read uncommitted. You may read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

"Both of these allows reading the data without locking the target row. " This is not true.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1186417/best-practice-for-using-snapshot-isolation-level
" SNAPSHOT isolation can result in blocking and deadlocks because transactions may be holding locks on versioned data that other transactions need to access."

There will be no lock on the row itself and hence writers will not block readers and readers will not block writers. Deadlocks are part of database engine as long as consistency is considered.
